# Вернулись или возвратились?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее: "они вернулись" или "они возвратились" и в чем разница между ними?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре ВОЗВРАТИТЬСЯ = ВЕРНУТЬСЯ. Т.е. в одном из значений это синонимы, обозначающие движение, ориентированное относительно конечного пункта. В другом значении - действие, выполняемое повторно. Практически во всех контекстах глаголы взаимозаменяемы.

Comment: А стилистической разницы тут нет? Первое слово выглядит немного более книжно, как мне кажется... 

"Вернись, я все прощу". Можно ли сказать "возвратись ко мне"? Слегка режет слух...

Comment: Приведенная вами фраза - почти "крылатая". Поэтому любое изменение воспринимается как режущее слух. Мне тоже казалось, что должны быть стилистические отличия. Проверила по разным словарям. Никаких помет, примеры самые разнообразные. Повторюсь, практически во всех контекстах глаголы взаимозаменяемы.